# python version for robot framework selenium2library (Windows10)

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Env: Windows 10 Pro

I installed python 2.7.9 and using `pip` installed `robotframework` and `robotframework-selenium2library` and it all worked fine with no errors.

Then I was doing some research and found that unless there is a reason for me to use 2.x versions of Python, I should stick with 3.x versions. Since 3.4 support already exists for *selenium2library* (read somewhere), so I decided to switch to it.

I uninstalled `python 2.7.9`  and installed `python 3.4` version. When I installed `robotframerwork`, I am getting the following:

> **C:\Users\username>**`pip install robotframework`
>   Downloading/unpacking RobotFramework
>     Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_username\RobotFramework\setup.py) egg_info for package RobotFramework
>       no previously-included directories found matching 'src\robot\htmldata\testdata'
>   Installing collected packages: RobotFramework
>     Running setup.py install for RobotFramework
>         File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\robot\running\timeouts\ironpython.py", line 57
>           raise self._error[0], self._error[1], self._error[2]
>                               ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>         File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\robot\running\timeouts\jython.py", line 56
>           raise self._error[0], self._error[1], self._error[2]
>                               ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>       no previously-included directories found matching 'src\robot\htmldata\testdata'
>       replacing interpreter in robot.bat and rebot.bat.
>   Successfully installed RobotFramework
>   Cleaning up...

When I did pip list I do see robotframework is installed.

```
C:\Users\username>pip list
pip (1.5.4)
robotframework (3.0)
setuptools (2.1)
```

Should I be concerned and stick to `Python 2.7.9`?

Comment: Selenium2LIbrary doesn't officially support python3 yet. At the time that I write this comment, the smart thing would be to stick with python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3.x then u can install Selenium2Library using this

```
pip install  https://github.com/HelioGuilherme66/robotframework-selenium2library/archive/v1.8.0a1.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

With python 2.7.9 you can only install robotframework 2.9

With python 3.X you can install robotframework 3.x+ but as Bryan Oakley said, Selenium2Library is not yet supported ;)